# Apache Camel - calling an external service through camel rest

Tags: rest, http, apache-camel

The idea is simple.I want to call an external rest service through a camel rest component.
Here is the code:

```
restConfiguration().component("jetty").host("localhost").port(8080).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

    rest("/api/v1").get("/test").to("direct:callExternalService");

    from("direct:callExternalService")
            .log("calling external service...")
            .to("https://example.com/api?param=1&bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

After calling http://localhost:8080/api/v1/test from browser, I get Connection timed out with following camel log (Obviously I have called the external service from browser and Postman and it works.):

```
2019-12-30 10:36:08,246 [qtp2143571436-35] INFO  route2 - calling external service...
2019-12-30 10:36:40,246 [qtp1213871206-34] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
2019-12-30 10:36:40,246 [qtp1213871206-34] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
2019-12-30 10:37:11,729 [qtp1213871206-34] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
2019-12-30 10:37:11,730 [qtp1213871206-34] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
2019-12-30 10:37:43,221 [qtp1213871206-34] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
2019-12-30 10:37:43,221 [qtp1213871206-34] INFO  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
2019-12-30 10:38:14,715 [qtp1213871206-34] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-pc-1577698556917-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-pc-1577698556917-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Is there the possibility that your request needs to go through a web proxy?

Comment: @TomDonohue exactly, the problem was the proxy. my request needed to go through a proxy server.